# SuiteScript 2.0 Search.Create filtering order status

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to get all the sales orders of a particular customer via the search function.

```
var filters = [
   ["mainline", "is", "T"], "and",
   ["entity", "anyOf", idCustomer], "and",
   ["status ", "anyOf", "Pending Fulfillment"]
];

var searchQuery = search.create({
   "type": search.Type.SALES_ORDER,
   "filters": filters
});

salesorders = searchQuery.run().getRange({"start": 0, "end": 1000});
```

This throws an error,

[image]

How do I get a search like this working?

Comment: Just  to reiterate what I mentioned in my other answer - have a look at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp, it is an invaluable tool for what you are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray space in your status filter; `"status "`, should be `"status"`.

You will also need to change the filter value from "Pending Fulfillment" to "SalesOrd:B" in order for your search to return any values.

```
["status", "anyof", "SalesOrd:B"]
```

Comment: There are many status I need to expand this to, how does SalesOrd:B represent the Pending Fulfillment.

Comment: Have a look here: http://blog.prolecto.com/2013/08/30/netsuite-searchfilter-transaction-internal-status-list/